# Capturing Copy Paste in Katalon

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

How do you capture copy and paste functions in Katalon Studio?

I am writing a Katalon script which requires the user to copy and paste a randomly generated security number.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys
```

and then (let us say you will double click to select the number):

```
WebUI.doubleClick('id-of-the-number-field')
WebUI.sendKeys('id-of-the-number-field', Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, 'c'))

WebUI.click('id-of-the-paste-field')
WebUI.sendKeys('id-of-the-paste-field', Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, 'v'))
```

Comment: the functions did work, however I just need to copy one part of the otp. But the codes are binding the whole text together. So when I doubleclick and copy, it copies the whole chunk of sentence. For example the otp is generated to be "ABCD-123456" So i only need to copy out the numbers instead of the alphabet. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: So you have a `String otp = "ABCD-123456"`. You can now use the groovy split method: `otp.split("-")`.

Comment: implement this in the code? If yes, I can't as this is a project i'm handling but I do not have access rights to change the coding. any other suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to change the coding (I'm presuming you are talking about the page coding). Scripts in Katalon Studio are written in Groovy programming language. So you can write the code above in the script. If you have a string "ABCD-123456", you can get the number part like this: `"ABCD-123456".split("-")[1]`. Try it yourself.

Comment: Hi @Mate Mrše, forgotten to mention that the "ABCD" is randomized as well. so the ID that is captured is the previous generated String. Can I still implement the above code in this situation? I did what was mention but it still does not copy the integer.

Comment: What does `println "ABCD-123456".split("-")[1]` do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text from the object and store it in a variable:

```
String s = WebUI.getText("your-testobject")
WebUI.setText("your-testobject", s)
```

Then you could do whatever you want with the string.